# Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{n}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{p}$ is continuous

Here, I am trying to prove by sequential criterion.

Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{p}$

I need to prove that if $x_n\to a$ then $f(x_n)\to f(a)$

I am choosing $y_n=f(x_n)=x_n^\frac{1}{p}$ and $b=f(a)=a^\frac{1}{n}$

Now, I consider $y_n^p-b^p=(y_n-b)(y_n^{p-1}+........+b^{p-1})$

$\Rightarrow |y_n-b|\le \frac{|y_n^p-b^p|}{|b^{p-1}|}\\\Rightarrow |f(x_n)-f(a)|\le \frac{|x_n-a|}{b^{p-1}}<\epsilon$

as $x_n\to a$

So, I proved for positive real numbers. How can I prove for negative real numbers? For example, for $x=-1$?

Comment: What is $p$? If you take $p=2$ then $f$ is not even defined as a function that maps $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @sobi ...we solve this problem with odd and even

Comment: @sobi..natural number

Comment: OP: if the domain depends on $p$, then you need to separate these cases out. As @Sobi states, if $p=2$, then the domain *can’t* be $\Bbb R$, though it could be $\Bbb R^+$ or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ only is defined on $[0,\infty)$ for even $n$. For odd $n$, write $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ where $x>0$ and $f(x)=-\sqrt[n]{-x}$ where $x<0$.

Comment: @nosrati....we prove for x<0  then n must be odd right

Comment: for odd $n$, when $x<0$ you can use $-\sqrt[n]{-x}$ for $-x>0$.